# FlowJS - number ... is incompatible with string

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Can somebody explain why I get the following FlowJS error with this code?

> *number [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTv5M.png) is incompatible with string [2]*
>
> (the white box around `number` indicates the flow error)
>   [image]

If I remove the final `map()`, the flow error goes away:

```
function splitKey(key: string | Array<string | number>): Array<any> {
  const arr = typeof key === 'string' ? key.split('.') : key;
  return arr.length === 1 && arr[0] === '' ? [] : arr;
}
```

Even weirder, if I map values to themselves (`map(k => k)`), it triggers the error. What is it about mapping values that confuses Flow in this situation?

```
function splitKey(key: string | Array<string | number>): Array<any> {
  const arr = typeof key === 'string' ? key.split('.') : key;
  return arr.length === 1 && arr[0] === '' ? [] : arr.map(k => k);
}
```

Comment: checking at [sandbox](https://flow.org/try) I've found this error occurs for v. 0.83.0 but for v 0.84.0 everything is fine

Comment: Thank you! Do you mind leaving a proper answer because this could definitely help others by encouraging them to upgrade whenever encountering weird issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [flow's playground](https://flow.org/try) we can see this error appears for 0.83.0 but has gone in 0.84.0

Unfortunately I don't see anything related to this question in [release notes](https://github.com/facebook/flow/releases/tag/v0.84.0) so root cause is still unknown.